# Wordpress Plugin for Soundcloud giving "Track currently not available"

Tags: wordpress, plugins, soundcloud

So I am using wordpress to build a website with the soundcloud plugin.  The shortcode for 3 out of 4 songs is working fine but the fourth just shows up as "Track currently not available".  The track is playable on soundcloud just fine.

Here is the webpage where its happening:

http://lostintheholler.com/epk/?page_id=13

and here is the track on soundcloud:

https://soundcloud.com/lostintheholler/07-take-it-and-go

The wordpress embed code from soundcloud works fine too but it doesn't have the look you get from using the plugin.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In you last embed track we can find :

```
<param name="movie" value="http://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=%3C%2Fcode%3E%3Ccode%3Ehttp%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F20974440&amp;color=905C18&amp;theme_color=FBE8CF">
```

There is some extra characters in the URL parameter :

```
%3C%2Fcode%3E%3Ccode%3E
```

Try to find where they're from and delete them and it would work like for 3 other tracks.